# Delete button next to corresponding inputfield

Tags: javascript, arrays, button

I have an array of number inputfields and need to put a delete button next to each. Here's the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/JCprog/99tp0n0e/2/) for reference.

Tried to make a function (see below) but cant make it work. Please help, Thanks in advance :)

```
  function delamount() {
     $(".delbtn").click(function() {

         var a = $(this).data('value');
         var b = $("#value" + a);

         b.value = '0.00';


     });
 }
```

Comment: one thing, you have inline event handler and also in the function, you attach another event handler to the same button?

Comment: The value you're setting to a? It's never defined. The data-value field you put on each input needs to be put on each button.

Comment: Thanks Will for your reply, I knew something was off. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things going on: first, your fiddle doesn't know to use jQuery. Second, yes you define an onclick and then you tell the onclick to bind the function on click, which becomes a massive repetative loop. Try this:

```js
var a, b;
  $(".delbtn").on("click", function() {

    a = $(this).data('for');
    b = $("#"+a);

    b.val('0.00');

  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="width: 25px; float:left;">
  <button data-for="value01" class="delbtn" id="delamt01">X</button>
  <button data-for="value02" class="delbtn" id="delamt02">X</button>
  <button data-for="value03" class="delbtn" id="delamt03">X</button>
  <button data-for="value04" class="delbtn" id="delamt04">X</button>
  <button data-for="value05" class="delbtn" id="delamt05">X</button>
</div>


<div style="width: 20%; float:left;">
  <input class="sizebox" type="number" id="value01" name="value01" value="0.00" />
  <br>
  <input class="sizebox" type="number" id="value02" name="value02" value="0.00" />
  <br>
  <input class="sizebox" type="number" id="value03" name="value03" value="0.00"/>
  <br>
  <input class="sizebox" type="number" id="value04" name="value04" value="0.00"/>
  <br>
  <input class="sizebox" type="number" id="value05" name="value05" value="0.00"/>
  <br>
</div>
```

I've removed the onclick, and bound the click handler via jQuery. I moved the data element to the button itself. Hope it helps!

Okay, I then made a change -- the data-value attribute is now data-for (much like the label's for attribute). This reduces the dependency on consistent naming of the target input. Other than that, pretty much the same.